# C String Input Error

Tags: c, string, input, output, character

I am confused about this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char name[30],ch;
    int i=0;
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter name: ");
    while(ch!='\n')
    {
        ch=getchar();
        name[i]=ch;
        i++;
    }
    name[i]='\0';
    printf("Name: %s",name);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, i input a number say "7" and press enter to get string line input. But it never takes input, instead It shows:

```
7
Enter name: Name:
```

I wanted to take a number and then in the next line, i wanted to take a string line and finally showing the output.

Help me in this. All i can understand is that when i press enter after giving the integer value that is creating problem. But i want input from the next line.

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read line by line. On the first line use `sscanf()` to get the number out of it. On the second line you can just use the whole line after removing the newline at the end.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407344/how-can-i-capture-a-string-from-a-function-in-c-that-returns-string

Comment: Also note that `ch` was *uninitialised* when you first tested it, moreover it should be `int ch` to match the return type of function `getchar`. Which allows the fuller implementation `while(ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)`

Comment: Use ```fflush(stdin);``` after the line ```printf("Enter name: ");``` . It will flush standard inputs such as Enter key.

Comment: Thank you everyone. fflush(stdin) worked perfectly.

Comment: Please be aware that `fflush` is not portable. It's a non-standard function supplied with some systems.

Comment: Then what could be  possible solution to this? I want to get input from the next line. @WeatherVane

Comment: Well, knowing there must a `newline` sitting in the input buffer after the `scanf` operation, you can read that in next and discard it, before starting the loop.